# why do I have ssl error while doing a conda install or simply run anaconda virtual environment?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, anaconda, x509certificate

I am trying to use anaconda on my windows laptop, got the ssl error, tried to "conda config --set ssl_verify false" and it makes no difference, any help or advise would be helpful.
$ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install -c conda-forge gdal`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 573, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 134, in _main
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 80, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 222, in install
    unknown=index_args['unknown'], prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 92, in get_index
    index = fetch_index(channel_priority_map, use_cache=use_cache)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 111, in fetch_index
    repodatas = collect_all_repodata(use_cache, tasks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\repodata.py", line 74, in collect_all_repodata
    repodatas = _collect_repodatas_serial(use_cache, tasks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\repodata.py", line 463, in _collect_repodatas_serial
    for url, schan, pri in tasks]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\repodata.py", line 463, in <listcomp>
    for url, schan, pri in tasks]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\repodata.py", line 109, in func
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\repodata.py", line 442, in fetch_repodata
    mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\repodata.py", line 138, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 835, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 392, in load_verify_locations
    self._ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 525, in load_verify_locations
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'Unknown error'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'system lib'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by uninstalling and re-installing anaconda. It looks like one of the pem is outdated.